# Determine the number of distinct nonzero components for the third order system

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, tensors

[image]

I'm learning tensor calculus and in part (b) it seams that all elements are zero. Here is my attempt. Am I missing something?

$A_{ijk} \ =-A_{ikj} =-A_{kij} =A_{kji} =A_{jki} =-A_{jik} =-A_{ijk} =0$